# UIView loaded with Nib autoresizing issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, interface-builder, orientation

I have a UIView subclass -

```
@interface DatePickerPopup : UIView
    UIToolbar *toolbar;
    UIDatePicker *datePicker;
@end

@implementation

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    NSArray *xib = 
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
            loadNibNamed:@"DatePickerPopup" 
                  owner:self 
                options:nil];
    self = [xib objectAtIndex:0];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

and the nib looks like -
[image: nib]
[image: ib autoresizing]

In my UIViewController containing the DatePickerPopup (datePopup):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    datePopup = [[DatePickerPopup alloc] initWithRect:CGRectZero];
    CGRect newFrame = datePopup.frame;
    newFrame.y = 200.0f; //lets say this aligns it to the bottom in portrait
    datePopup.frame = newFrame;

    // Normally happens when accessory button pressed but for brevity...
    [self.view.superview addSubview:datePopup];
}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:
    (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
    duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || 
        toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        self.datePopup.frame = 
            CGRectMake(0.0f, newHeightPortrait, screen.size.width, 260.0f);
    }
    else
    {
        self.datePopup.frame = 
            CGRectMake(0.0f, newHeightLandscape, screen.size.width, 260.0f);
    }
}
```

However, this gets stretched out for some reason when the orientation changes the view gets stretched to the height of the screen bounds - the navigation bar...

after viewDidLoad
[image: after viewDidLoad]

after willAutorotate...
[image: after willAutorotate...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your view controller appears to be managed by a navigation controller, calling `[self.view.superview addSubview:datePopup];` adds your popup as a subview of a `UIViewControllerWrapperView`, which is one of the private classes UIKit uses to implement the functionality of `UINavigationController`.  Messing with UIKit's private view hierarchy is always risky.  In this case, based on the behavior you're seeing, it seems likely that UIKit expects any subview of `UIViewControllerWrapperView` to be a view controller's view, so it resizes your popup accordingly.

I think the safest way to resolve this is to have your view controller's view be a wrapper that contains your tableView and, when necessary, your popup view.  Unfortunately using a wrapper view means that the view controller can't be a `UITableViewController`.  You'll have to change the superclass to `UIViewController`, set a custom `tableView` property, and manually adopt the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols.

Note: You might be tempted to add your popover as a subview of your window, but I'm not recommending that because `UIWindow` only autorotates its topmost subview corresponding to a view controller.  This means that if you add your popover to your window, it won't autorotate.

---

EDIT: BTW, by reassigning `self = [xib objectAtIndex:0];` in `initWithFrame:`, you're leaking the object that was originally alloc'd.  If you're going to reassign self in this way, you should release the existing object first.

Comment: Not yet.  `[self alloc]` returns an object with a +1 reference count.  Even before `initWithFrame:` executes, `self` already points at this object.  You're reassigning self to point at a different object, which leaks the one originally allocated by the caller in `[self alloc]`.  To avoid this leak, you need `[self release]` before the `self = [xib objectAtIndex:0];` line.

Comment: your right, that seems janky. Im going to take it out of the init.

Comment: I think that's a good call.  You could load the NIB in the class method.  That would be less weird.  Was the other part of my answer correct?

Comment: I've been looking into it today, and it is right... however I don't really want to do your first suggestion :-x The problem is it is already a tableViewController (acctually a subclass of a subclass of tableViewController) Apples DateCell example uses the window technique you explicitly told me not to use. perhaps I can remove it from its window parent in willAnimateRotation... and rebuild it in didRotate...? I am going to try it now.

Comment: I understand.  I've wrestled with similar decisions on past projects, and gone to great lengths (excessive lengths, in hindsight) to avoid converting my UITableViewControllers into vanilla UIViewControllers.  Adding your view to the window can work.  You'll just need to rotate the view manually using its `transform` property.

Answer (score 0):

Add the

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

method in the viewController class and return YES. If this method returns YES, only then will the device support landscape orientation. Try out this extra code and see if it helps...
You can set the frame size for landscape in this method itself instead of the current method. PS: I just saw you've used a UIView instead of controller...you might want to change to controller.

Comment: Check and check, have that method implemented and frame is getting set on willAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

Comment: It's not clear from the image, so is the picker also not being rotated in landscape? that might be a hint...